# Request mapping not working between jsp page and a method in controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc project. Im trying to delete an announcement but im getting a 404 error and it cant seem to find the method. All my other mapping is working fine and Ive done this the same way so I cant seem to figure out where I went wrong

This is my link for the button to delete the announcement, it is correctly getting the ID in the url so i know this works

```
<c:url value="/deleteAnnouncement?id=" var="deleteAnnouncementURL" />

<security:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
<a href= "${deleteAnnouncementURL}${announcements.id}" class= "btn-outline-danger btn-sm pull-right">Delete</a> 
</security:authorize>
```

This is my method in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/deleteAnnouncement/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteAnnouncement(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model)
    {

        Announcement announcement = announcementService.findOne(id);
        announcementService.deleteAnnouncement(announcement);
        return "success";
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is 2019. JSPs should have died 15 years ago. Don't use them, they are horrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are sending the request is wrong.

From front end the value you are sending as a request parameter but in backend you are receiving it as a path variable.

Change value="/deleteAnnouncement?id=

to

value="/deleteAnnouncement

and add slash between URL and id like below.

${deleteAnnouncementURL}/${announcements.id}